# KDE that better-preserves percentile distributions

Tags: python, quantiles, kernel-smoothing, resampling

My understanding is that a Gaussian KDE, because the kernel is symmetric, preserves the statistical mean of a distribution.  For my particular case, I'd really prefer a KDE that preserved the median, or even better, the median and roughly the 1-sigma region.  Is there a transformation or procedure for doing this?

Here the red histogram is my data, and the blue curve is resampled using the [gaussian KDE from the scipy python package (scipy.stats.gaussian_kde)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), in log-space (i.e. I transform the x variable to log space, then the resampled values back to linear space).  The vertical solid-lines are the averages, and match nicely.  The vertical dashed lines are the percentiles corresponding to -1, 0, 1 standard deviations respectively --- and those are systematically biased.  Over a large number of iterations the blue (KDE) median values (center dashed lines) are always significantly above the red (data) median values.

[image]

Comment: KDE (as long as the kernel has mean 0) actually preserves the mean, but transform-KDE-backtransform doesn't. (KDE unavoidably inflates variance with a non-negative kernel). If there was a monotonic transformation to a situation where mean was equal to median (e.g. because of symmetry) then it would preserve the median (even through transforming back)

Comment: By "preserve the median", do you mean you want the median of the KDE to equal the sample median of the data?

Comment: @user20160 yes, that's it